# Crear sliders de imagenes wordpress con múltiples efectos de transición

Tags: wordpress-plugin, slider

quisiera pedir su ayuda por favor, quisiera saber si existe algun plugin para hacer galeria de imagenes con multiples efectos de transicion, al estilo del programa: “wowsliders”, es que cuando utilizo “wowsliders” no me deja subir el plugins para mi sitio, me da error como que no tengo permisos, gracias por adelantado !!

Comment: Yo utilizo Slider Revolution gratuito, y esta muy bien. Tiene muchas opciones para configurar , crear animaciones, escribir texto en las imágenes, etc En este caso, era la primera vez que lo usaba, y entendí su funcionamiento pronto.
Y la verdad sea dicha, habré utilizado el 8 %. Da mucho juego. Echa vistazo [en su web](https://revolution.themepunch.com)  https://revolution.themepunch.com

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente recomendacion!!!

Comment: Hola, el sitio que me recomiendas esta increible, pero puedieras decirme como descargar algunos temas de slider revolution por favor, si hay alguno para wordpress que sea gratis, mucho mejor.

Comment: Instalas [Slider Revolution](https://revolution.themepunch.com/) sin mas.  Y luego a jugar con la cantidad de funcionalidad que tiene, es increible. Claro, es de pago, en el tema que yo use ya venia instalado. Pero creo que no vale mucho, desde 25 Euros lo tienes. De todas formas revisa eso de los permisos, ¿sera que no tienes permisos de administrador ? ...O quizá que “wowsliders” también requiere licencia...??

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo Slider Revolution gratuito, y esta muy bien. Tiene muchas opciones para configurar , crear animaciones, escribir texto en las imágenes, etc En este caso, era la primera vez que lo usaba, y entendí su funcionamiento pronto.
Y la verdad sea dicha, habré utilizado el 8 %. Da mucho juego.
Echa un vistazo [en su web](https://revolution.themepunch.com/)
https://revolution.themepunch.com/